# Утечка памяти в Android WebView

Tags: android, java, webview

При добавлении поддержки JavaScript ***setJavaScriptEnabled(true)***, когда перехожу по ссылкам, приложение начинает занимать очень много памяти, когда не добавляю поддержку, то всё работает нормально, не знаю почему так, помогите разобраться.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    mWebContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.web_container);
    mWebContainer.addView(mWebView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
}

private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);

        return true;
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mWebContainer.removeAllViews();
        mWebView.destroy();
        mWebView = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

Создавал простой WebView - такая же утечка памяти.

Comment: Ну вообще это можно более или менее объяснить тем, что интерпретаторам (в частности, встроенному интерпретатору JavaScript) требуется приличное количество оперативной памяти для работы.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте без включения JavaScript. Все постоянно жалуются на утечку памяти при включении этой фичи.

Comment: Без включения всё норм,но без JavaScript не могу,шас более менее провёл оптимизацию,приложение пока держиться